# My code is not running but i have no errors

Tags: javascript

The project is about making a rock paper scissors game using functions and loops etc.

the code below is how the project looks

1. the first function is to get the randomized computer choice
2. the second function is to get the user or players choice
3. the third function is to play the game and check if the player won or the computer won
4. the final function is to create a for loop to run the third function a certain number of times to see who is the winner of the game

Been working on it since and have no idea why it doesn't work

````js
```
  function getComputerChoice() {
  let values = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

function getPlayerChoice() {
  let getChoice = "rock";
  let value = getChoice.trim();
  let lowCase = value.toLowerCase();
  let capitalize = lowCase.charAt(0).toUpperCase + lowCase.slice(1);
  while (!["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].includes(capitalize)) {
value = getChoice.trim();
lowCase = value.toLowerCase();
capitalize = lowCase.charAt(0).toUpperCase + lowCase.slice(1);
  }
  return capitalize;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let games = "";
  if (
(playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
(playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock")
  ) {
return (games =
  "player loses!! " + computerSelection + " beats " + playerSelection);
  } else if (
(playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") ||
(playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
(playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors")
  ) {
return (games =
  "player Wins!! " + playerSelection + " beats " + computerSelection);
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
return (games =
  "it a tie noice " + playerSelection + " v " + computerSelection);
  } else {
return (games = "euphoria");
  }
}

function game() {
  let playerScores = 0;
  let computerScores = 0;
  let computerSelection = "";
  let playerSelection = "";

  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
if (
  playRound(
    "player loses!! " + computerSelection + " beats " + playerSelection
  )
) {
  computerScores += 1;
  console.log(
    "you lost this round!! boo hoo!! scores are " +
      computerScores +
      " v " +
      playerScores
  );
} else if (
  playRound(
    "player Wins!! " + playerSelection + " beats " + computerSelection
  )
) {
  playerScores += 1;
  console.log(
    "you Won this round!! hurray!! scores are " +
      computerScores +
      " v " +
      playerScores
  );
}
  }
  if (playerScores > computerScores) {
console.log("congratulations you won this round");
  } else if (playerScores < computerScores) {
console.log("im sorry you lost this round");
  } else {
console.log("there is a problem");
  }
}

game();
```
````

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Your if statements in game() are checking the return of playRound, but it doesn't return anything and it requires two arguments to be passed but you aren't passing those either.

Comment: I think it is running but it is not doing anything.  Note that `playRound` expects two arguments but you are just passing it a human readable string-- I suspect this is part of your problem.

Comment: An easy Debugging tip: include console.log("message"); statements throughout your code to track its path.

Comment: also at line 10, `toUpperCase` should be `toUpperCase()`

Comment: I tried to open your code with visual studio code, but the browser was overloaded and can't start the page. I think your code is over complicated. you can do it more simple. 
here is a [simpler code for the game](https://codepen.io/Mad7Dragon/pen/BaxPVPa)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that playRound() is returning anything:

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let games = '';
  if (
    (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock")
  ) {
    games = "player loses!! " + computerSelection + " beats " + playerSelection;
    // ADD RETURN HERE

  } else if (
    (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") ||
    (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors")
  ) {
    games = "player Wins!! " + playerSelection + " beats " + computerSelection;
    // ADD RETURN HERE
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    games = "it a tie noice " + playerSelection + " v " + computerSelection;
    // ADD RETURN HERE
  } else {
    games = "euphoria";
    // ADD RETURN HERE
  }
}
```

**Explanation**
In your game() function definition you are checking if(playRound()). playRound is not returning anything so this is interpreted as a void function, hence, the if will always evaluate to false.

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions I tried the but they didn't work and It won't run in the console and not returning errors either

Comment: Hm, can you try refactoring it so that the result of playRound is return 1 (if player wins), return 2 (if computer wins), and return 3 (if tie)? Then you can simply run an if-statement in game like so: if(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) == 1){ console.log("Player wins!")}

Comment: I did some backtracking and realized the bug came from the pllayerChoice function. it was not returning anything from that function

Comment: Nice! Glad you found the answer on your own. Sorry couldn't have been of more help!

Comment: nah its because ur suggested thing that I was able too get my brain to work